# Modifying a spinner arrow in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to modify a spinner in Android according to this image.

[image: Image of the spinner]

This is my code for the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/black_border"
    android:scrollbarSize="13sp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/triangle"
    android:entries="@array/spinner_array"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: The background should contain the arrow and have different states (normal, pressed etc). See how to build an example [here](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: I have added a rounded border drawable as the border. Problem is how to place the arrow image android:drawableright isnt working

Comment: can u tell me how to get exactly the spinner as it is in the image

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Here is your `Spinner` mentioned in `XML` file.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/spinner_style"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

You have to create `spinner_style Style` in `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="announcement_spinner_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Here is `gradient_spinner Drawable` used in `spinner_style`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />

                    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

In

```
<bitmap android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
```

this tag you can use give Spinner Arrow.